# Cant format and insert data from input into the database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple form like this:

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/api/transaction/saveTransaction}" th:object="${transaction}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" placeholder="Enter a amount" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <input type="text" th:field="*{note}" placeholder="Enter a note" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Wallet</button>
</form>
```

As you can see I have field to pick a date here:

```
<input type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
errors<EOL>Field error in object 'transaction' on field 'date': rejected value [2022-12-14]; codes [typeMismatch.transaction.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [transaction.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date] for value '2022-12-14'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-12-14]]]
```

This is how that field look in entity:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "mm-DD-yyyy")
@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;
```

I tried already to find something that can help me to solve this but without any success, I tried to change format but nothing has changed, still error.

Also to mention, I tried with both `sql.Date` and `util.Date`

Comment: the passed date input is diffrent i.e. `2022-12-14 -> yyyy-mm-dd` and the format you mentioned in the code is `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "mm-DD-yyyy")`, Please change the date format or pass the correct date.

Comment: Yeah, I changed to `(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` and it works, but how I can stay on `(pattern = "mm-DD-yyyy")`? Where I need to change that in thymeleaf?

Comment: try using `${#dates.format(date, 'mm-DD-yyyy')}"` in `<input type="date" th:field="${#dates.format(date, 'mm-DD-yyyy')}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">`

Comment: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '#dates' available as request attribute` that is error, its same if I change `#dates` to `#date`

Comment: Could you please provide some minimal reproducible example, as the issue is surely about the format not getting accepted.